# Looping through individual dicts and inserting into a nested dict

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested

I'm looking to loop through individual nested dictionaries being pulled in from a database and update a single new dictionary with all the nested dictionaries. I'm using a counter to assign key values to the dictionaries being pulled in but the logic is off and I'm having trouble getting my desired output.
My CursorByName assigns the proper keys and values to the data.

**Code:**

```
counter = 1
newdict = {}
dictofdict = {}
for row in CursorByName(cursor):
    while counter < 4:
        dictofdict = {counter : row}
        newdict.update(dictofdict)
        print(newdict)
        counter += 1
```

**Output**:

```
{1: {key1:value1}}
{1: {key1:value1}, 2: {key2:value2}}
{1: {key1:value1}, 2: {key2:value2}, 3: {key3:value3}}
```

**Target Output**:

```
{1: {key1:value1}, 2: {key2:value2}, 3: {key3:value3}, 4: {key4:value4}, etc}
```

Comment: There appears to be nothing wrong with what you're doing. You just need to print once after the loop instead of once per iteration. Also I would do `while counter <= 4`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I cant believe little that detail tripped me up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dict comprehension:

```
In [1]: d = {i: {'key{}'.format(i): 'value{}'.format(i)} for i in range(1, 4)}

In [2]: d
Out[2]: {1: {'key1': 'value1'}, 2: {'key2': 'value2'}, 3: {'key3': 'value3'}}
```